# Bolding text when dt element is clicked (and staying that way until clicked again)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my question for today:

How do you make a *dt* tag element from HTML appear **bold** once clicked, and stay bold until another *dt* element is clicked and/or the section with the drop-down dt is closed?

I'm using a Bootstrap 2.x/3 compliant css sheet, and am trying to figure out how to do this without needing to modify my hard code or delve into JavaScript (though if those are the only viable options, I'm all ears).

Right now my code snippet is this:

```
dt, .close { cursor:pointer; color:#093A7F !important; font-weight:normal; }
dt:active, dt:focus { font-weight:bold !important; }
```

Again, the idea is to have the Question stay **bold** until the corresponding Answer 'section' has been closed. Currently the above code only bolds the text when it's actively clicked.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Add a `tabindex` attribute to the element:

```
<dl>
    <dt tabindex="1">title</dt>
    <dd>content</dd>
    <dt tabindex="2">title</dt>
    <dd>content</dd>
</dl>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9h8w/

Answer (score 0):

There might be a solution where you could do that with `radio` elements, that have the same `name` attribute. But the styling is not the easiest and I think at the end you will have to use Javascript.

Comment: That was my guess as well. I have a colleague looking into how to do it primarily with JS, while I'm investigating the css side. So far I've nothing. :/ EDIT: Maybe with an 'onStateChange()' handler or something?